# Export part of the namespace of a class

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, using-statement

I have a class that includes an `enum`:

```
class appearance{
  // ... stuff ...
  enum color {BLUE, RED, GREEN};
};
```

I would like to attach part of the namespace (with `using`) so that I can refer to the value of the `BLUE` simply as `BLUE`, rather than `appearance::BLUE`. At the same time, I would like to keep the `enum` within the `class{}`, since I think that is most natural. I have tried various combinations of `namespace` and `using`, but to no avail.

Any suggestions ???

Comment: I had a similar problem: to shorten the name to an enum. `long::path::to::enum` where `to` was the class containing the enum. As I could not forward to a custom short labeled namespace I decided to subclass from class `to`: `class Mine : public To{ public: using long::path::to; private: Mine() {}; };` As you can see I forbid to generate instances of this class by a private constructor, so I could now use it in a much shorter way `Mine::enum`. Without type conversion, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it can be done. AFAIK, you can use `using appearance::color` in another class or structure as stipulated [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/using_directive.htm).

> A using declaration in a class A may
>   name one of the following:
>
> - A member of a base class of A
> - A member of an anonymous union that is a member of a base class of A
> - An enumerator for an enumeration type that is a member of a base class of A

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with a class-scoped enum. Probably the only way to achieve something similar is to enclose the enum in its own distinct namespace and then use that where needed to being in the enum.

EDIT: In this question [How do you import an enum into a different namespace in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293279/how-do-you-import-an-enum-into-a-different-namespace-in-c) I show one possible way to import an enum from one namespace into another, but I don't believe it would work (as-is anyway) for this class case.

Answer (score 1):

As Jacob said you can't do this directly, but you can make it work by encapsulating the enum within it's own namespace.

```
namespace enums{
        enum color
        {BLUE
        ,RED
        ,GREEN};
} // namespace enums


using namespace enums;
class Foo
{
    int Bar(){return BLUE;}
}
```

something like that should work...

Comment: The OP mentioned "I would like to keep the enum within the class{}".