# how to typdef an enum of one namespace inside another and use ist c++

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you import an enum into a different namespace in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293279/how-do-you-import-an-enum-into-a-different-namespace-in-c)

How can following enum namespace problem been solved?

```
namespace A {
    typedef enum ABar { a, b };

    void foo( ABar xx ) {}
}

namespace B {
    typedef enum A::ABar BBar;

        void foo( BBar xx ) { A::foo( xx ); } 
}

int main() {
    B::foo( B::a ); // 'a' : is not a member of 'B'
                    // 'a' : undeclared identifier
}
```

Answer (score 8):

While you typedef a type, you don't import the symbols defined in that namespace. So while you can write:

```
int main() {
    B::BBar enumVariable=A::a;
}
```

you cannot access `B::a` as this symbol does not exist.

A partial walkaround and, in my opinion, a way to make the code more clean, although also a bit more longer to write, is to pack every enum into its own struct, e.g.:

```
struct ABar {
    enum Type {a, b};
};

typedef ABar BBar;

int main() {
    ABar::Type var=ABar::a;
    BBar::Type var2=BBar::a;
}
```

You will be able to, if you still need it, to pack ABar into a namespace and normally typedef in another namespace too.

Comment: I see the problem.. packing the enum into an own class is no option because it's an boost enum ;-)

Comment: boost::date_time::weekdays/months_of_year and boost::date_time::nth_kday_of_month< Date_t >::week_num

Comment: I never actually recognized this problem with namespaces, but still I developed the habit of wrapping each enum in a struct. In my opinion it looks much cleaner than the usual prefixing of enum values, and having to write ABar::Type instead of ABar is a small price. So +1 (even if it doesn't solve the OP's problem :) ).

Comment: @DrFroid: Have you considered namespace aliasing ? `namespace bdt = boost::date_time;`, `bdt::weekdays wd = bdt::monday;`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the declaration of an enum does not only create the type, but it also declares the enumerated identifiers with the given values. When you do a typedef you are only creating a local alias to the type, but the values are not brought to the new namespace. That is, the compiler will see `B::BBar` and it will know by means of the typedef that you are referring to `A::ABar`. But while processing the `B::a`, there is nothing in `B` namespace that refers to that.

For that to work, you would have to also bring `a` and `b` into the new namespace, and that is not done by the typedef, as they are not types. Anyway it is *achievable* like:

```
namespace A {
   enum ABar {
       a, b
   };
}
namespace B {
   typedef ::A::ABar BBar;
   using ::A::a;
   using ::A::b;
}
```

I would not recommend doing it, as it will become a maintenance problem quite rapidly (you will have to remember to update both namespaces with each change to the original one.

As to how to deal with the problem, the workaround proposed by @CygnusX1 is actually a good option, and if you are using a C++0x compiler the language allows for a similar idiom as it allows to access the enumerated values through the enum type:

```
namespace A {
   enum ABar { a,b };
}
namespace B {
   typedef A::ABar BBar;
}
int main() {
   std::cout << B::BBar::a << std::endl; // extra enum qualification
}
```

Comment: ok, thnaks. this helps me a lot.. Poor thing, that vc 9 is not C++0x compatible, because this looks like the best solution for me. But Cygnus way of solving that issue works also for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can not typedef an enum. You can use it :

```
namespace B {
   using A::ABar;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is modified example, that works :

```
namespace A {
    enum ABar { a, b };

    void foo( ABar xx ) {}
}
namespace B {
    using A::ABar;        // 'ABar' : is injected into namespace 'B'
    using A::a;           // 'a' : is injected into namespace 'B'

        void foo( ABar xx ) { A::foo( xx ); }
}
int main() {
    B::foo( B::a );
}
```

However, as CygnusX1 and David pointed out, the above is polluting the namespace B, and it is better to do it like this :

```
namespace A {
    enum ABar { a, b };

    void foo( ABar xx ) {}
}
namespace B {
        void foo( A::ABar xx ) { A::foo( xx ); }
}
int main() {
    B::foo( A::a );
}
```

There is also a third option, to typedef it, but properly:

```
namespace B {
    typedef A::ABar BBar;

        void foo( BBar xx ) { A::foo( xx ); } 
}
```

but you still can not do this:

```
B::foo( B::a ); // 'a' : is not a member of 'B'
                // 'a' : undeclared identifier
```

because BBar is just an alias of A::ABar.

Comment: sorry, I changed the example thus it represents my real problem...

Comment: Have you actually tried it? My initial guess was this, but this does not work.

Comment: problem is that I need to define an own enum, that mirrors the one of the other enum...

Comment: @David Now I did. The added example compiles.

Comment: Is "_You can not typedef an enum_" really true? The other answers, and my own experiment with `typedef X A::ABar;`, seem to imply that it's valid.
Indeed, to my understanding, anything you can alias with `using` that isn't a template alias you can do with `typedef`.

Comment: @boycy Bad wording. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545233/476681) put it better.