# Pulling C++ Enum Class Members Into the Global Namespace

Tags: c++, enums

Is there a `using` directive that imports the members of an `enum class` directly into the global namespace of a compilation unit?

We have:

```
enum Lexeme {....lots of names...};

bool Matches(int lookAhead, Lexeme lxm);
```

This is risky because users frequently forget that the first argument of `Matches` means "matches either" and write:

```
if (Matches(ADD,SUB)) ...
```

The C++ compiler is perfectly happy taking `ADD` as an int.

So I tried making `Lexeme` an `enum class`:

```
enum class Lexeme { ...}
```

This catches the error.  But now my problem is that all the code that uses `Lexeme` constants must write the `enum class` name:

```
if (Matches(Lexeme::ADD,Lexeme::SUB)) ...
```

Is there a `using` directive, or another trick, to pull all of the `Lexeme::*` names into the current scope?  Note, most tokens are used in a class (I get that properly qualifying the constants is one of the safety mechanisms of `enum class`).

Perhaps a better plan is to change `Matches` to `MatchesAt`, or something, to avoid the problem?  But I wanted to know the rules for C++ and C++XX, at least.

What I tried:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293279/) is related, but doesn't address the required `enum class` prefixes.

I also tried something like `using foo::bar::Lexeme`; but alas to no avail.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @DrewDormann I believe OP is asking for a shortcut to avoid typing `Lexeme::` everytime the enum is used.

Comment: You can make an integer wrapper class not convertible to anything else and make some constants out of it. `class Lexeme{int value;}; inline constexpr Lexeme const ADD{1};`

Comment: Yes. I updated it to make it clearer (see the italics at the top) and better title.

Comment: @VTT so `const static int` members of a class?, but won't those type as raw integers, thus not solving the implicit conversion problem (treating them as ints)?

Comment: No, I suggest to use class instances constants.

Comment: Yes! @VTT exactly what I was looking for. Can you put that in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an integer wrapper class not convertible to anything else and make some constants out of it.

```
struct Lexeme
{
   private: int m_value;

   public: explicit constexpr Lexeme(int value) noexcept
   : m_value{value}
   {}
};

inline constexpr Lexeme const ADD{1};
inline constexpr Lexeme const SUB{2};
```

It would probably be a good idea to overload some operators for this class, at least equality and less than.

Comment: Could also work if `Lexeme` is `enum class`:  `inline constexpr Lexeme ADD {Lexeme::ADD};`

Answer (score 1):

On a different note, a way to avoid writing `Lexeme::` every time would be just to create a shorter alias:

```
enum class Lexeme { /* lotsa names */ };
using L = Lexeme;

if (Matches(3, L::SUB)) //...
```

This works well if there is only one or two files where these values are used extensively, and other uses are sparse. I have just had to use a similar solution where I had a Parameter class that read things from XML. I have a `enum class ElementType { INTEGER, BOOLEAN, /* etc*/ }` and a parsing infrastructure. Within the parser file, I have:

```
using ET = ElementType;

template<ET et>
struct parser;

// Specializations for each ElementType
template<>
struct parser<ET::INTEGER> {
    using type = int;
    int parseSingle(const string& s) // ...
}
```

While outside this file I just have a few usages of ElementType::* constants and I use the full name of the enum class. Should this become too much of a burden, nothing prevents me from ading that alias to a different file.

Comment: This is a good alternative too. Lexical tokens typically don't leak too far, and a short prefix is almost as good as the other. Thanks.